# ESI within a varnish cascade?

Tags: varnish

we want to set up a varnish cascade so that we have something like level 1 and level 2 caching. This means on a request 
- varnish level 1 processes and routes to 
- varnish level 2 which routes to 
- application

Question: if the application now adds esi within the content, is it possible to define something like namespaces something that some esi are handled within level 2 varnish and other ones within level 1 varnish?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Varnish to process ESI one needs to add

```
set beresp.do_esi = true;
```

to the "vcl_backend_response" ("vcl_fetch" in Varnish 3) in ones VCL.

As this can be done conditionally, e.g.

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (bereq.url == "/test.html") {
       set beresp.do_esi = true; // Do ESI processing
    }
}
```

you could control if ESI is processed in one or the other Varnish instance.
Also see: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/users-guide/esi.html